# Should users be asked to increase their accept rates?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed from time to time, users leave comments requesting other users increase their accept rate.  I've seen this done in the original SE trilogy communities, so I guess it's accepted behavior there.  Is this behavior accepted in our community?  If users don't feel they've received an "acceptable" answer on questions, should they be punished in future questions for not accepting an answer on previous questions?  Are folks really not answering questions because of low accept rates?

Comment: As to your question, "Are folks really not answering questions because of low accept rates?", yes, that would be right - what's the point in answering if the user never accepts or responds with comments?

Comment: @Steven To help people.

Comment: It goes two ways. From my perspective, if they never comment, upvote or accept, then they are not participating in the community and the evidence suggests that I'm not even helping.  I know what user this is about and he had a 0% accept rate over a number of questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't badger users to accept answers.

While it happens on the original trilogy it's not universally accepted and if you flag a "(please) improve your accept rate" comment it gets deleted immediately with no moderator involvement.

All acceptance means is that the OP found that answer the most helpful. If there isn't an answer that fits then there is no obligation on the OP to accept *any* answer.

If the OP comments that the answer helped but hasn't actually accepted then *perhaps* adding a comment linking to the [Meta Stack Overflow post on how acceptance works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) *might* be in  order, but please don't do it in a accusatory way.

Comment: When flagging these comments, what should the flag reason be?

Comment: @Tester101 - "not constructive / off-topic"

Comment: Going through old posts with no accepted answers. If the user is active, I ask how they solved it. Should I not? Should I suggest they answer their own question, then?